# Entity framework one database context multiple website sync problem

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a 'web ui app' and 'web ui admin panel app' both using same database context but any entity change in 'web ui' doesn't show in admin panel or the exact opposite. How can I refresh context all query or how can Iconfigure context to not load entities?

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public DatabaseConfiguration()
    {

    }
}
```

sorry for bad english, thanks for helping.

Comment: someone help me please

Comment: You'll need to provide detail about how you are using your database context, but in most cases like this it is because your DbContext is too long-lived, such as by using something like a Static DbContext at the session level rather than per request. DbContexts should be short-lived, constructed as needed. DbContexts do *not* refresh cached data with changes from the database.